# IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the columns from dataframe whose correlation with another column is greater than certain values like below.

```
df.loc[:, (df.corr()['col'] <= -0.05) | (df.corr()['col'] >= 0.05)]
```

But I am getting below error,

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Also if I try to select the columns with variance > 1, I get the same error,

```
df.loc[;df.var() > 1 ].
```

Why I am getting indexing error. I want to filter the columns of dataframe if correlation of that column with another columns is between -0.05 and 0.05.

Can someone assist in resolving this issue. I am not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: can someone plz help here

Comment: you should consider accepting the answer provided, and next time please provide data and code along with your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found what's your problem.

First I tried to build my own testing set, unfortunately everything worked nicely:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
    "A": [1.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.1],
    "B": [1.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.9, 5.0, 6.0]
})
df.loc[:, (df.corr()['col'] <= -0.05) | (df.corr()['col'] >= 0.05)]
```

I got :

```
   col    B
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.1
2  3.0  3.0
3  4.0  3.9
4  5.0  5.0
5  6.0  6.0
```

But then, after reading again your error, I thought maybe there are some columns in your data the `corr()` method is just ignoring such as column with an `object` dtype.

If I build a new testing set with textual columns, I get the same error as you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
    "A": [1.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.1],
    "B": [1.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.9, 5.0, 6.0],
    "C": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
})
df.corr()['col'] >= 0.05
df.loc[:, (df.corr()['col'] <= -0.05) | (df.corr()['col'] >= 0.05)]
```

Then I got:

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

One way of fixing this is by doing so:

```
df = df.drop(columns=df.corr().query("-0.05 < col < 0.05").index)
```

Note: Please remind you'll have quicker and more relevant answers if you provide a full sample of the non-working code so that your error can be reproduced easily ;)