# IndexingError when filtering a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, python-re

I am trying to filter out a Data frame by selecting different values in the rows like this:

```
booleans = []

for result in dfcolumn:
    if re.search('1/1', result):
        booleans.append(True)
    else:
        booleans.append(False)
print(booleans[0:5])
print(len(booleans))

Filtered=pd.Series(booleans)
df2=df[Filtered]
df2
```

However, every time I try this I get this error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How is "dfcolumn" defined?

Comment: I suggest googling the error message. There are a lot of hits for it. See if any of them help you solve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359869/indexingerror-unalignable-boolean-series-provided-as-indexer-index-of-the-bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
filtered = pd.Series([True, False, True], index=df.index)
```

so...

```
filtered = pd.Series(booleans, index=df.index)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) What does that do? im a bit new to python...

Comment: pandas Series have a row index just like DataFrames. With this I created the Series using the index of your df. pandas needs to align the indexes of both objects to perform the filtering (also for other operations like concat etc). This should always work if both Series and df have a standard numeric index. So maybe your df had a different index?

Comment: How I solve raise ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (614)?